# Adding an SQL procedure to have a summary of bookings for each client

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a multi disciplinary booking database in MySql. I have normalized tables already. How do I create a procedure that provides a summary of all bookings for each client.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Client_Booking_Summary(
    IN client_id INT,
    IN year INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        services.service_name,
        COUNT(*) AS total_bookings,
        SUM(services.service_fee) AS total_fees
    FROM
        bookings
        JOIN services
            ON bookings.service_id = services.service_id
    WHERE
        bookings.client_id = client_id AND YEAR(bookings.booking_date) = year
    GROUP BY
        services.service_name;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you should never use variable names that are equal to a column name or mysql reserved words, so change client_id and year to _client_id and _year and use that.

Comment: Another common naming convention is to use `p_` prefix for function parameters, e.g. `p_client_id` and `p_year`.

Comment: If you want a summary for each client, remove the `client_id` parameter, add `bookings.client_id` to the `SELECT` list, and use `GROUP BY bookings.client_id, services.service_name`